# Why is the syntax error coming in erlang spawn function call - " syntax error before: ')' "?

Tags: concurrency, erlang, erl

This is the code  i am running in an online compiler

```
-module(helloworld). 
-export([start/0, call/2]). 

start() -> 
% error in the below line as  syntax error before: ')'
Pid = spawn(?MODULE, call, ["hello","world"] ),
io:fwrite("~p",[Pid]).


call(Arg1, Arg2) -> 
io:format("~p ~p~n", [Arg1, Arg2]).
```

Comment: If the online compiler gives that error for this code then it is wrong.

Comment: Please provide the online compile (web ?) that you used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried erlang compiler online in `tutorialspoint` and can reproduce problem. I guess it got some problem in compiler, it's not your fault, just continue investigate `Erlang` :)

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_erlang_online.php

You can change to this compiler online

> https://paiza.io/en/projects/new?language=erlang

//Edit:
The issue may become from editer of `tutorialspoint`. It makes compiler don't understand function `spawn/3`, please add double quoute `''` for `spawn/3` function like below, It will compile and run:

```
 Pid = 'spawn'(?MODULE, call, ["hello","world"] ),
```

Comment: That's weird.... I tried tutorialspoint, and if you change `spawn` to `apply`, then it compiles and runs...